# JTCalendar showing wrong date in Calendar

Tags: ios, swift, calendar, timezone, jtcalendar

I make JTCalendar into custom view , all thing were working fine until I change timezone to EST, the calendar is showing 27 days for February but the actual number of days in 2018 is 28.

It happen when I start the app in default timezone and then changing the timezone to New York from settings, then when I open calendar, layout is wrong. After this when I tap into date 24 and result is date 23. only happen when I change timezone from IST to EST.[image]

Comment: You may need to make changes in the JTCalender files. I have got a similar issue once, maybe need to set the timezone.

Comment: another approach will be to reload the calendar inside viewwillappear as per the local timezone.

Comment: thanks @SaadChaudhry will check this.

Comment: February doesn't have 27 days accounted for, if you check carefully, the first day of February is the 31 of January, not the 1st. It's just an "offset" due to the TimeZone and conversion.

Comment: thanks @Larme we fixed the issue with the help from "Saad Chaudhry"

Comment: Thanks @Lena, Happy Coding, Our [iosandroidchaosoverflow](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26424/iosandroidchaosoverflow) chat room will might be of your interest.